# PHP comparing int from database with POST[int]

Tags: php, mysql, post, compare, int

I'm having issues with the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_POST['productname'];
$sql= "SELECT quantity FROM products WHERE productid='$name'";
$amount= $sql + 0;
$quantitysold = $_POST['quantitysold']; 
$amountsold = $quantitysold + 0;
var_dump($amountsold);
var_dump($amount);

if($amountsold > $amount){
    echo 'Not enough product';}

else if($name && $quantitysold){
    $query = $db->query("UPDATE products SET quantity=quantity-$quantitysold
    WHERE productid='$name'");
    $query = $db->query("DELETE FROM products WHERE quantity<'1'");} 

else{
    echo 'Incomplete Data';}

}
```

The issue is that sql is read as a string, instead of the integer I hoped to redirect it to. This means that I am unable to compare $amount and $quantitysold.

I have recently started learning PHP, so this might be might a rookie mistake.

Comment: You need to feed your $sql string into a function such as $result = $connection->query($sql);    But this is far from a complete answer because you need a bunch of other lines to create a connection to your sql server and extract data from the results.   Do some tutorials on 'PDO mysql'  (google 'pdo mysql tutorial')

Comment: Did you read *any* tutorials on how to do this, or did you just start coding? Where did you get the idea that this would work: `$sql= "SELECT quantity FROM products WHERE productid='$name'";
$amount= $sql + 0;`

Answer (score 2):

use filter input from php functions

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "productname",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$sql= "SELECT quantity FROM products WHERE productid=$name";
$amount= $sql + 0;
$quantitysold = $_POST['quantitysold']; 
$amountsold = $quantitysold + 0;
var_dump($amountsold);
var_dump($amount);

if($amountsold > $amount){
    echo 'Not enough product';}

else if($name && $quantitysold){
    $query = $db->query("UPDATE products SET quantity=quantity-$quantitysold
    WHERE productid=$name");
    $query = $db->query("DELETE FROM products WHERE quantity<'1'");} 

else{
    echo 'Incomplete Data';}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code doesn't pass the sql query string to the sql engine.  Below is how it would be done if you were using PDO ([Php Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php))

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdatabasename","yourusername","yourpassword");
    $name = $_POST['productname'];
    $sql= "SELECT quantity FROM products WHERE productid=?";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($name));
    $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $amount= $row[0];

// the rest of your code
```